# JSTL EL invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: in Tomcat 7

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jstl, el

I'm trying to get this old JSP project running in Tomcat 7, JRE7 but getting this error in most of the pages in the project. Can any  one please shed some light whats happening?

The code looks like:

```
<c:set var="structClass">
    <c:if test="${empty param.class}">template</c:if>
    <c:if test="${not empty param.class}">${param.class}</c:if>
</c:set>
```

The error looks like:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/templates/template.jsp (line: 77, column: 4) "${empty param.class}" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${empty param.class}]
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:585)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

it is because of **'class'** keyword in the expression try to use

```
<c:if test="${empty param['class']}">template</c:if>
<c:if test="${not empty param['class']}">${param['class']}</c:if>
```

refer http://geekomatic.ch/2011/03/22/1300804080000.html

Comment: now the error changes to => org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: deferredExpression

Comment: http://geekomatic.ch/2011/03/22/1300804080000.html I added -Dorg.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK=true and that solved the issue.... thanks for the link!!!

Comment: ${something.new} also says same error because of `new` keyword. Thanks.